Prove that the Hausdorff distance and Area metric are not equivalent on the set of all bounded plane polygons.
Prove that the area metric, $d_{\Delta}$, is not equivalent to the Hausdorff distance between two sets. The book and definitions are here [1] (4.Dx & 4.Ex). The approaches I’ve tried are here:
Let the area metric = a(A,B).
Let the Hausdorff metric = b(A,B).
Define $B^b=B^b({\lambda}, {\epsilon})$.
Pick an arbitrary ${\delta} \in B^b$ and define $B^a=B^a({\delta},{\Sigma})$.
Then, our goal is to find a ${\Sigma}$ s.t. $\forall p \in B^a, p \in B^b$.
$p \in B^a$
Note that: $d_{\Delta}(p,\delta)$ takes on 3 values, one of which, is $S(p)+S(\delta)$, where, obviously, S and $\delta$ share no intersection. This value specifically has nothing to do with the distance between p and $\delta$, so we have to try our best to get rid of it.
We can do this successfully whenever $S(\delta)=\Sigma$. So from here, $d_{\Delta}(p,\delta)$ takes on two values, either 0 or it’s definition.
When $d_{\Delta}(p,\delta)=0$, then ${p = \delta}$. When $d_{\Delta}(p,\delta)=S(p)+S(\delta)-2S(p \cap \delta)$, for this to satisfy $S(p)+S(\delta)-2S(p \cap \delta)=\Sigma+S(p)-2S(\delta \cap p)<\Sigma. \\ \Rightarrow S(p)\le 2S(\delta\cap p)$.
That’s how far I’ve gotten.
I’m aware that his question has been answered in another post, however I’m looking for an answer that uses examples of typical balls in that metric. For example, like one open ball in one metric is not open in the other metric.

Let $d_H$ be the Hausdorff metric, $d_\triangle$ the area metric.  Let $A$ be the unit square $[0,1] \times [0,1]$, and choose $r > 0$.  Let $B_r^H(A)$ be the open ball with respect to $d_H$ of radius $r$ centered at $A$.  We show that there exists no $s > 0$ such that $B_s^\triangle(A) \subseteq B_r^H(A)$, where $B_s^\triangle(A)$ is the open ball with respect to $d_\triangle$ of radius $s$ centered at $A$.
Choose $s > 0$, let $h = 2r$, and let $P_h$ be the polygon consisting of the union of $A$ and a rectangle of width $\frac{s}{4r}$ and height $h$ with its left corner at $(.5,1)$.  For any bounded polygon $X$, let $S(X)$ denote the area of $X$.  We have
\begin{align}
     d_\triangle(A,P_h) &= S(A) + S(P_h) - 2(A \cap P_h)\\
     & = 1 + 1 + \frac{s}{2} - 2\\
     & = \frac{s}{2}
\end{align}
which implies that $P_h \in B_s^\triangle(A)$.
On the other hand, $d_H(A,P_h) = 2r > r$, which means $P_h \notin B_r^H(A)$.  So for a given $s > 0$, we can always find a bounded polygon which is in $B_s^\triangle(A)$ but is not in $B_r^H(A)$.  Thus there exists no $s > 0$ such that $B_s^\triangle(A) \subseteq B_r^H(A)$, which means that $d_\triangle$ and $d_H$ are not topologically equivalent on the set of bounded polygons on the plane.
